# Logging User Login in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a Python application on AppEngine that requires users to log in.
Is there any way to write a log entry on logging in?

Users could hit the log in screen from any URL and will reload pages throughout their session so adding it to code would add numerous entries when all I want is one at the point of authentication.

Comment: Have you tried logging to the Datastore?

Comment: Use wsgi middle ware, create a session, check if the users.get_current_user() is not None, if has a value and the session hasn't been set to logged in, then set the logged in state and write a log entry.  This isn't exactly what you want, but will be close.  Other wise you need to manage the login process yourself.

Comment: @TimHoffman, that's quite an elegant solution, thanks very much. You're right that it's not perfect but it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Log only if its been some time since they entered the app.
if you really want to do it at the login level hou can but you will need to setup SSO on the domain.

Comment: Sorry, should have pointed out that SSO is not an option, there's a strong use of Google accounts in the organisation already.